# Wix:How Can I Create Shortcut Without Registry

Tags: wix, registry

In our project, we are going to remove registry entries to make non-admin users able to install it.

Our current code is as follow, I tried to comment out the  section from the XML file but failed.

Is there any chance that we can create the shotcut without registry key? thanks.

```
    <DirectoryRef Id="ApplicationProgramsFolder">
  <Component Id="ApplicationShortcut" Guid="C85221B1-70CA-455D-B322-093543BD4DF0">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationStartMenuShortcut"
              Name="$(var.ProductName)"
              Description="$(var.ProductDescription)"
              Target="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]OMOffline.exe"
              WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />
    <Shortcut Id="RemoteAssistance"
              Name="Request Remote Assistance"
              Description="Starts Remote Assistance and creates a password-protected RA ticket that is attached to a new Remote Assistance invitation. The User must enter the e-mail address of the Helper in the To field to send the message to the Helper."
              Target="[SystemFolder]MSRA.exe"
              Arguments="/email"/>
    <Shortcut Id="UninstallProduct"
              Name="Uninstall $(var.ProductName)"
              Target="[SystemFolder]msiexec.exe"
              Arguments="/x [ProductCode] SQLSERVER=&quot;[SQLSERVER]&quot;"
              Description="Uninstalls $(var.ProductName)"  />
    <RemoveFolder Id="RemoveApplicationProgramsFolder"
                  Directory="ApplicationProgramsFolder"
                  On="uninstall"/>
    <!--<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.ProductManufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)" Name="shortcutsinstalled" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>-->
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>


<DirectoryRef Id="DesktopFolder">
  <Component Id="DesktopShortcut" Guid="C03900DF-FFD8-44B8-AA42-1BC72BB9E1F4">
    <Shortcut Id="ApplicationDesktopShortcut"
      Name="$(var.ProductName)"
      Description="$(var.ProductDescription)"
      Target="[APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY]OMOffline.exe"
      WorkingDirectory="APPLICATIONROOTDIRECTORY" />
    <!--<RegistryValue Root="HKCU" Key="Software\$(var.ProductManufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)" Name="desktopshortcutinstalled" Type="integer" Value="1" KeyPath="yes"/>-->
  </Component>
</DirectoryRef>
```

Comment: Wix has made the simple act of creating a shortcut painful. If I want to create a shortcut in Windows all I need Target and Working folder. Wix forces me to enter a load of other stuff I don't know like WTF is an advertised shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

HKCU is per-User entry, That should not Interfere with your goal of Making per-user Install. You can use http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rflaming/archive/2006/09/30/778690.aspx to make a package per-user Installable.

To answer your question, I tried installation without registryvalue. Program Was allowed to build (with ICE38/ICE41 error), I was able to see the link post Installation of MSI